# C# ASP.NET Korzh Query Builder Custom Value Editor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to find out from someone if they have worked with [Korzh Query Builder](http://devtools.korzh.com/) before.

If so, have you tried implementing a Custom Value Editor, and if so, how did you do this, and if possible do you have any links/documentation.

The provided exaples/documentation is a bit shoddy.

I have spent some time trying to figure this out, as the List examples are very slow once the number of items breach the 1000+ mark.

Any help/articles/links in this regrds will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Korzh support ?

Comment: I have sent them a message, but no response as yet X-( lets hope someone here has done something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will depend very much on what exactly custom value editor you are trying to build.
First of all, what edition of EasyQuery do you use (WinForms, WebForms, WPF or Silverlight)?
Please describe more in details what you are trying to achieve as a final result?

Also, what kind of List examples are "very slow"? If you use SQLLIST value editor for some attribute then the speed of its work depends on SQL statement you defined and your connection to the database but nothing about EasyQuery itself.

One remark. 
The product you mentioned is called [EasyQuery](http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-component/) component library or EasyQuery.NET (if we mention .NET version only). Korzh Query Builder is a quite old standalone application which was written on Delphi and worked with databases through BDE.

Comment: Hi @Sergiy, I am using the version for ASP.net as mentioned in the question. Also, this is when I create a Custom list or Sql List. I can see that the query is returning fine, it is slow when the ListValueEditor is trying to Render the control with more than a 1000 List Items. Furthermore, I would like to create a Custom Value Editor of my own design, and would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: Yes you are right. It's can take quite long time since all those "more than 1000 items" must be transferred between your server and client browser and then must be rendered there.

Comment: OK, so that given. Do you know how to create a Custom Value Editor?

Comment: As for your task. It's more likely you need new XElement descendant control which will replace the default one used to render those list items. This new control can be AJAX'ified so it will not render all items at once but will asynchronously download them by small portions.

Comment: This is starting to sound promising. Do you know of any examples/documentation taht i can read?

Comment: There is a library reference for the base class (XElement) and all its descendants.

Comment: But what is more important - is to create some specification for new control (how it should look, its behavior). It's possible we will create it ourselves and add in the next update of EasyQuery.

Comment: That is perfect. I will have a look at the assembly documentation, and do some more searches on line. If you dont have specific examples, maybe I can figure it out, and will let you know either by this thread, or your website responses. Thanks for steaing me in the right direction, and the chat. The controls are very usefull. Regards, Adriaan